# What is typically involved to repair a internal combustion engine that has a cylinder misfiring?

Tags: engine, obd-ii, misfire, cylinder, combustion-chamber

I have a vehicle with a cylinder misfiring (according to my OBD-II code reader).  I have decided to have a mechanic repair it, as I have never performed a similar motor vehicle repair.

Note that the only consistent symptom besides throwing the cylinder misfire OBD-II code is a little accelerator hesitation.

Not consistent was also some really bad (perhaps metal on metal - hard to tell) grinding sound for about 10-20 seconds when first driving after not using the vehicle for over 2 months. It sounded real bad, but resolved on its own before I could even turn around and park.

To help me evaluate different mechanics, I would like to know what is likely required to properly diagnose and repair this problem.  With the knowledge you provide, I will hopefully be able to filter out the scammers and find a trustworthy mechanic for this job.

Comment: What are the symptoms you experience? The underlying root causes, and thereby the work involved is difficult to estimate if you only provide an suspicion of the fault

Comment: I fixed mine by wiggling the wire to the injector on the misfiring cylinder.

Comment: @Martin Great question! Thank you. I updated my question to answer your question. :)

Comment: Clear the code and drive it for a bit to see if the code comes back. All sort of bad stuff happens if the vehicle is sitting, some of it goes away after a short drive.

Comment: @EᑎOT That was my original plan, but the answer for the following question have made me think it could be an undesirable plan: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/77548/pros-and-cons-of-driving-a-vehicle-with-a-misfiring-cylinder

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket, I didn't mean just to keep driving it. What I meant is - drive it for a couple days, then check for codes again.

Comment: @EᑎOT Right... but from the answers to that question, it sounded like people were advising not to drive it at all.  I have almost no experience with misfiring cylinders, so I honestly have no idea what's best.  I don't want to damage the engine, but I also don't want to pay for an expensive mechanic that isn't needed.

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons for a cylinder misfire, many of them you can check for yourself. Easy to check are:

- Spark plugs: a worn plug, badly gapped plug or a fouled plug
- Spark plug not fully in: check to make sure the plugs are inserted properly
- Spark plug cables: worn, pinched or greasy cables may not transfer electricity properly. Also make sure the connections are clean
- Coils: it's hard to check these without the right equipment, but easy to replace

Less easy:

- Cylinder compression
- Fuel Injectors
- Fuel Pressure
- Valve seating

It would make sense to check the easy things yourself and possibly save yourself some money.

Comment: Thank you. That is a great list, and as you mention, I can check many of those items myself.